# Can't display woocommerce products on shop page after adding rewrite rules

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What i'm trying to do is to prettify standard woocommerce filter urls.

I mean change this filter url `sitename.com/shop/?color=blue` to this `sitename.com/shop/color-blue/`

I've added rewrite rules:

```
    add_action('init', 'filter_rewrite');
    function filter_rewrite() {
        $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
        $page_data = get_post( $shop_page_id );

        if( ! is_object($page_data) ) {
            return;
        }

        add_rewrite_rule(
            $page_data->post_name . '/color-([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?pagename=' . $page_data->post_name . '&color=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }
```

and then updated permalinks.

But when I open page `sitename.com/shop/color-blue/` there are no products and some errors in Woocommerce product filters widgets like

> Notice: Trying to get property 'post_count' of non-object in SITEPATH/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-price-filter.php on line 69

I'm using standard woocommerce archive-product loop to display products:

```
    <?php
    if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {
        if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                 *
                 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/part-product-preview' );
            }
        }

    } else {
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
         *
         * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
         */
    ?>
```

Function `wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' )` returns `0` while `woocommerce_product_loop()` returns `1`

Page `sitename.com/shop/` is working fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.